# Support of a Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-measure

Let $G:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be a distribution function (that is, non-decreasing and right-continuous) with support $\text{supp}(G)$ define as:

$$\text{supp}(G)=\{r\in [0,1]: G(r+\varepsilon)-G(r-\varepsilon)>0\;\forall \varepsilon>0\}.$$

Associated with $G$, there exists a Lebesgue-Stieltjes probability measure $\mu_{G}$ s.t. for $I=(a,b]$ with $0<a<b\le 1$, $\mu_{G}(I)=G(b)-G(a)$. The support of $\mu_{G}$ is the smallest closed set with measure 1.

1. Show that $\text{supp}(\mu_{G})=\text{supp}(G)$.
2. If $S\in[0,1]\backslash \text{supp}(G)$, then $\mu_{G}(S)=0$, but the converse not necessarily true. Under what conditions does the converse hold?

Comment: What is your definition of $\operatorname{supp}(G)$?

Comment: $\text{supp}(G)=\{r\in [0,1]: G(r+\varepsilon)-G(r-\varepsilon)>0\;\;\forall \varepsilon>0\}$ and $\text{supp}(\mu_{G})=\cap\{C\in \mathcal{C}: \mu_{G}(C)=1\}$, where $\mathcal{C}$ is the collection of closed subsets of $[0,1]$. I have managed to show that $\text{supp}(G)$ is a closed subset, so it belongs to $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: your definition of $\operatorname{supp}(\mu_G)$ makes the thing difficult. Do you know the equivalence to  $\operatorname{supp}(\mu_G) = \{ r : \mu_G(U) > 0 \; \forall U \text{ open with } r\in U \}$?

Comment: Yes. If $\text{supp}(\mu_G)$ is the intersection of all closed subsets of $[0,1]$ with measure 1, then $\text{supp}(G)^{c}=\cup\{U\in \mathcal{U}: \mu_{G}(U)=0\}$ where $\mathcal{U}$ is the collection of open sets of $[0,1]$. But this equals $\{r: \mu_{G}(U)=0\;\text{for some U open with $r\in U$}\}$. Setting $(\text{supp}(\mu_{G})^{c})^{c}=\text{supp}(\mu_{G})$ gives the result. Is that correct?

Comment: your reasoning looks okay. Anyway I posted an answer with a (different) proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Item 1:**

For brevity, let $S_1 = \operatorname{supp}(\mu_G)$, $S_2 = \operatorname{supp}(G)$, and $S_3 = \{r\in[0,1] : \forall U\text{ open in } [0, 1] \text{ with } r\in U \implies \mu_G(U) > 0 \}$.

1. I will show $S_1 = S_3$ first: Notice that $S_1$ is closed and $\mu_G(S_1) = 1$. Let $r\in S_1$ and $U$ open with $r\in U$. Then, $S_1\setminus U$ is closed and thus we have $\mu_G(S_1 \setminus U) < 1$. In particular, we have 
   $$\mu_G(U) \ge \mu_G(S_1 \cap U) = 1 - \mu_G(S_1 \setminus U) > 0.$$
   On other hand, let $r\in S_3$ and $C$ be closed with $\mu_G(C) = 1$. Assume $r\not\in C$. Then, there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $r$ disjoint to $C$. But that implies
   $$ \mu_G(C \cup U) = \mu_G(C) + \mu_G(U) > 1,$$
   which contradicts that $\mu_G([0, 1]) = 1$.
2. *Proof for $S_2\subseteq S_3$:*
   Let $r\in S_2$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. Then, we have
   $$ 0 < \mu_G((r - \varepsilon, r + \varepsilon)) \le \mu_G((r - \varepsilon, r + \varepsilon]) = G(r+\varepsilon) - G(r - \varepsilon) $$
   and therefore $r\in S_3$.
3. *Proof for $S_3\subseteq S_2$:*
   Now, let $r\in S_3$, $U$ be open with $r\in U$, and $\varepsilon > 0$ with $(r-\varepsilon, r+\varepsilon) \subseteq U$. Then, we have
   $$ 0 < G(r+\varepsilon/2) - G(r - \varepsilon/2) = \mu_G((r - \varepsilon / 2, r + \varepsilon / 2]) \le \mu_G((r - \varepsilon, r + \varepsilon)) \le \mu_G(U) $$
   and therefore $r\in S_2$.

**For Item 2:**

The question is a little bit vague. It is surely sufficient that $S$ has non-empty interior.

Comment: Thanks! You define $\text{supp}(\mu_{G})$ simply as the smallest closed subset $S$ of $[0,1]$ s.t. $\mu_{G}(S)=1$, right? With respect to item 1, I was looking for some conditions to say that a set in $\text{supp}(G)$ has certainly a positive measure, or maybe some conditions to say that a set has positive measure if and only if it belongs to the support. I was thinking about the Lebesgue measure, where each singleton has zero measure, but it belongs to the support (the real line).

Comment: @CaioLorecchio: Oh my bad. I got confused with the $S_i$'s. I fixed them. For Item 2, as you said, one need to impose some conditions on $S$.

Comment: I got the point anyway, thanks :). I think you changed the subscripts in steps 2 and 3. In step 2, you want to show that $S_3\subseteq S_2$ and in step 3, you want to show that $S_2\subseteq S_3$, right? One last question. It is sufficient that $S$ has non-empty interior because if that is the case, $\mu_{G}(S)\ge \mu_{G}(\text{int}(S))>0$, since $\text{int}(S)$ is open and any point in it belongs to the support. Is that correct?

Comment: @CaioLorecchio yes. ${}{}{}$